# link_to no route matches only after AJAX create of a post

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Basically every time I create a post with AJAX, it won't render the new post because of this line:

```
<%= link_to "promote", vote_scribble_path(:scribble_id => scribble.id, :vote => true), remote: true, method: :post%>
```

**THE LINK ABOVE ACTUALLY WORKS**, it just prevents ajax render of newly created post.

here is the error that i get when trying to create new post with AJAX, it does actually create the post and it would render new post without the line above. After refresh of a page the new post with a working link appear.

```
  Rendered scribbles/_scribbles.html.erb (18.9ms)
  Rendered scribbles/create.js.erb (19.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 48ms

ActionController::RoutingError - No route matches {:action=>"vote", :controller=>"scribbles", :scribble_id=>155, :vote=>true}:
```

Here is the full code in action:

**create.js.erb** updates posts list after create

```
 /*Replace the html of the div post_lists with the updated new one*/
 $("#posts_list").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => "scribbles/scribbles") ) %>");
```

**feedlist.html** does render all of the posts

```
        <div id="posts_list">
        <%=render :partial => 'scribbles/scribbles', :locals => {:scribbles => @scribbles}%>
        </div>
```

**scribbles/_scribbles.html** that link_to single line prevents ajax render. but it works.

```
  <% @scribbles.each do |scribble| %>
<%= link_to "promote", vote_scribble_path(:scribble_id => scribble.id, :vote => true), remote: true, method: :post%>
  <%end%>
```

even something like this gives me an error

```
<%= link_to "promote", vote_scribble_path()%>

vote_scribble_path(:scribble_id => scribble.id, :vote => true), remote: true, method: :post, :put,:get %> tried them all still same error
```

THE LINK WORKS IT JUST DOESN'T RENDER after AJAX CREATE, after page refresh everything is fine. **any ideas why ?**

```
  resources :scribbles do
        member do
      post 'vote'
    end
    end
```

**scribble_controller.rb**

```
def vote
  @scribble = Scribble.find(params[:scribble_id])
  @vote = params[:vote]
  if @vote == "true"
    @v = :up
    current_user.vote(@scribble, :direction => @v)
  else
    current_user.unvote_for(@scribble)
  end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js{}
    end
end
```

Comment: Your routes suggests that your controller is expecting `params[:id]`, not `params[:scribble_id]`. Change `vote_scribble_path(:scribble_id => scribble.id [...])` to `vote_scribble_path(:id => scribble.id [...])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be passing `id` instead of `scribble_id` in your `link`.

```
<%= link_to "promote", vote_scribble_path(:id => scribble.id, :vote => true), remote: true, method: :post%>
```

because as per your defined routes, the generated route for `vote` action would be:

```
vote_scribble POST   /scribbles/:id/vote(.:format)        scribbles#vote
```

which you can check by running `rake routes`.

As you can see `vote_scribble_path` is expecting an `id` placeholder and not a `scribble_id` which is why you receive the error as Rails cannot find a matching route in your application for `scribbles#vote` action with placeholder `:scribble_id`.

Comment: HAHAHHAHA, THANK YOU!!! it worked. I'll be able to accept answer a bit latter. you answered it too fast :D